# cron.schedule is running past my given time frame?

Tags: node.js, cron

I have a cron.schedule running on a heroku server and it's supposed to run once every five minutes (that works) between the hours of 8AM and 10PM (that doesn't work). It keeps running past 10PM for some reason, and I cannot seem to figure it out. I must be writing something wrong. Anyone have some experience with cron that can help me out?

```
cron.schedule('*/5 08-22 * * *', () => {})
```

Comment: Some versions of cron may not like "08". try `8-22`

Comment: @John3136 I tried it without the 0 but it still doesn't work for some reason.